# How to conditionally aggregate a column based on another

Tags: google-bigquery

a row of my data looks like this

`[someId, someBool, someInt]`

I'm looking for a way to aggregate someInt (to put them in an `array` specifically).

I use a GROUP BY clause to group by the `someId` field, then I can aggregate all the `someInt` using `ARRAY_AGG` but I only want to include rows where `someBool=TRUE`. How to approach this the right way ?

PS: It might be relevant to note what I got several booleans like `someBool` and would like to output to a different array each time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ARRAY_AGG` with `IGNORE NULLS`, e.g.:

```
ARRAY_AGG(IF(someBool IS NOT TRUE, NULL, someId) IGNORE NULLS)
```

This will only aggregate the IDs for which `someBool` is true. If you have multiple boolean columns that you want to use in the condition, you can `AND` them together or use a `CASE WHEN ...` or whatever other kind of condition you want that produces `NULL` in order to exclude a value.

Comment: Thanks that did it perfectly !